# Scoped CSS styling - How to apply a CSS style to a specific block of HTML?

Tags: html, css

I was reading up on the `scoped` property for `<style>` tags and was wondering what the best method for applying a style to a specific part of your DOM, since `scoped` is not supported by all browsers, and if I want it to work in chrome I have to set up some flags in the browser itself.

Looking at the example below, the `scoped` property for me does not work. I can see this being solved by using more specific selectors in my CSS, but now lets say I have a small section that doesn't have classes or anything, but would like to apply styling to it, it can mess up a lot of other things in my web page.

```html
<article>
  <div>The scoped attribute allows for you to include style elements mid-document.
   Inside rules only apply to the parent element.</div>
  <p>This text should be black. If it is red your browser does not support the scoped attribute.</p>
  <section>
    <style scoped>
      p { color: red; }
    </style>
    <p>This should be red.</p>
  </section>
</article>
```

Are there any reliable methods for applying a style block OR importing a stylesheet to be applied to a specific portion of HTML on my web page?

Comment: I would recommend you to apply a wrapper element with a `class`. Say you cannot assign a `class` to any of your element or say you are restricted to change the DOM, than best you can do is to use specific selectors as you already mentioned.

Comment: There is a [polyfill in jQuery for scoped CSS](https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin), though I would definitely think about whether or not the scoped CSS is appropriate for your use-case.

Comment: @Quantastical so that essentially makes all browsers compatible with the `scoped` property so long as the user has JS enabled? I think most of the time I will be able to find/use a specific selector, I was just curious about the functionality of this

Comment: Yes, that is the crux of polyfills...to provide additional functionality to non-compliant browsers and, yes, JS will need to be enabled. I have never used it, nor have ever had a need for scoped CSS. I can see some potential uses when sharing blocks of code with 3rd parties or something, but those instances are pretty rare. I also have never seen any human users browsing the internet with JS disabled (despite it being possible to do so).

Comment: If you want to avoid JS, just write `article > section:last-child > p` for a selector...